# Как заполнить массивы в разных процессах

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Мне нужно вывести сложные расчеты массивов в разные процессы. Но у меня не получается получить доступ к массиву в самой функции процесса. Можно подробнее, как это сделать.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np

nambers = [1, 2]
a1 = []
a2 = []
print(a1, a2)

def print_func(namber):
    if namber == 1:
        a1 = np.random.random(50)
    if namber == 2:
        a2 = np.random.random(50)


procs = []

for namber in nambers:
    proc = Process(target=print_func, args=(namber,))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()

print('после', a1, a2)
```

P.S. Всем спасибо за ответы! От себя добавлю, как решение ниже, код с использованием очередей:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import numpy as np


a1 = []
a2 = []
print('до', a1, a2)

def print_func(q):
    q.put(np.random.random(50))

procs = []

for i in range(0, 2):
    q = Queue()
    proc = Process(target=print_func, args=(q, ))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()
    if i == 0:
        a1 = q.get()
    if i == 1:
        a2 = q.get()

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()

print('после', a1, a2)
```

Comment: Доступ то вы можете получить, написав предварительно `global a1, a2`, но все такие изменения останутся внутри каждого из процессов. Лучше используйте `Pool`, передавайте в функцию аргументы и получайте потом результат из неё. Тогда в основной процесс всё попадёт. Можно и другими способами, но это самый простой.

Comment: Да с глобал попробовал, данные за пределами функции не изменяются.

Comment: Они не изменяются за пределами процесса. Вам просто нужно осознать, что вообще происходит, в каком процессе что работает. У каждого процесса своя отдельная копия памяти. Родительский процесс не имеет доступа к памяти других процессов напрямую, у него своя, изначальная копия этих списков остаётся.

Comment: А для чего тогда Process? Ведь запускаются они на лету, пробовал таймсллеп. Цикл быстро запускает процессы и они ожидают истечения timesleep.

Comment: Если вам принципиален Process посмотрите тут как вернуть значение из него https://stackoverflow.com/a/10415215/8324991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для синхронизации между процессами можно использовать объект `Manager`.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import numpy as np


def print_func(namber):
    global first_array
    global second_array
    if namber == 1:
        a1 = np.random.random(50)
        first_array += a1
    if namber == 2:
        a2 = np.random.random(50)
        second_array += a2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    procs = []
    with Manager() as manager:
        first_array = manager.list()
        second_array = manager.list()

        numbers = [1, 2]
        for number in numbers:
            proc = Process(target=print_func, args=(number,))
            procs.append(proc)
            proc.start()

        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()
        print(first_array)
        print(second_array)
```

Тут вы регистрируете менеджер `with Manager() as manager:` и создаете 2 массива к которым можно будет обращаться из любого процесса. Это лишь один из вариантов, подробнее в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes). Но в вашем случае это кажется излишнем, правильнее, на мой взгляд, будет вернуть значение из процесса.